# TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable python

Tags: python, class, boolean

whenever I try run this code, I receive a TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable.
How could I fix this code to make it so that when I try and print bike.blue() I get a boolean value?

```
class Colour():
    def __init__(self):
        self.blue = False

    def blue(self) -> bool:
        return self.blue

bike = Colour()
print(bike.blue())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `__init__` method, you create an attribute `blue` on the instance. This shadows the method `blue()` defined on your class, so you can no longer access the method as an attribute of the instance. `self.blue()` then is the same as `False()` and you can see why that gives you an error.

Name the instance attribute something else, such as `_blue`.

Comment: Or, given there's no real benefit to the method, just keep the attribute name `blue`, and delete the definition of the `blue` method, so you'd use `bike.blue` (without call parens). Not what the OP requested (they want the call parens for some reason), but the reasonable way to do it.

Comment: I assume this is a toy example to show the problem, but usually you'd be right on there.

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

When you define the class, `self.blue` is a function.  But when your `__init__` runs, you erase the function, and assign a boolean.  After that, `obj.blue` returns the boolean, not the function.

It is never a good idea to give a class variable the same name as a member function.